# Вывод массива в C++ (При сравнении массивов)

Tags: c++

Задается 2 массива a и b, нужно вывести массив имеющий наименьшее кол-во положительных элементов. 
Пример: Массив a { 1, 2,3},
массив b { -4, -5, 6}
программа выводит рандомное число -33686019.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, n, el1 = 0, el2 = 0, z, f;
    cout << " kol-vo elementov v massive n=";
    cin >> n;
    int *a = new int[n];
    int *b = new int[n];
    cout << "       Vvedi elemeti dlya I massiva: ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    cout << "       Vvedi elemeti dlya II massiva: ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> b[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > 0) el1++;
        if (b[i] > 0) el2++;
    }
    if (el1 > el2) cout << "1 massive \n:" << a[i] << ' ';
    if (el1 < el2) cout << "2 massive \n:" << b[i] << ' ';
    if (el1 == el2) cout << "\n Oni ravni";
    delete[]a;
    delete[]b;
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А что, оба массива имеют один и тот же размер? Что-то я не вижу, где это сказано у вас в условии задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Значение `i` к тому моменту как вы делаете

```
if (el1 > el2) cout << "1 massive \n:" << a[i] << ' ';
if (el1 < el2) cout << "2 massive \n:" << b[i] << ' ';
if (el1 == el2) cout << "\n Oni ravni";
```

равно `n`, т.е. является недопустимым индексом для доступа в ваши массивы. В результате ваша попытка вывести элемент `a[i]` (или `b[i]`) производит доступ за пределы массива и выводит содержащийся там мусор. Этот мусор и есть ваше "рандомное число".

Зачем вы вообще пытаетесь выводить этот странный элемент `a[i]`? Вывод массива делается так же, как вы делали и ввод массива: вручную, поэлементно.

P.S. Зачем нужны переменные `z` и `f`? И какой смысл вы вкладываете в `system("pause");` после `return 0;`?